# How can I send a different application to the tray with C#?

Tags: c#, taskbar, systray

I tried searching for examples, but all I find are how to send your own application to the systray.  I want to hit a button on my form and have, say, Notepad vanish.  Doesn't even really have to go to the tray..  just disappearing from sight and from the taskbar would be fine since I can use my own app interface to restore it.

Any examples out there?  Thanks!

Comment: There is no interface for putting another application in the notification area. Each application decides how it wants to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is not possible.

Each application must call Windows itself to put it in the tray. It then also needs a Notify Icon and a Context Menu. So there is no way a third-party app can provide that to another app.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, I currently use an app that does that (http://www.ghacks.net/2008/10/09/tray-everything/) but my problem is the auto-minimize-when-seen chokes on programs launched via DOS as it's within the cmd process.  I figured if it's not too hard to hide, then I could just make something wherein I pass the program to minimize to the app as an argument.

*shrug*